# How to pass an int array to an ActionResult?

Tags: c#, razor

It's a simple question, yet one I've been struggling with. I'd just like to send a parameter which is an int array to my ActionResult. Every time I have tried it just comes back as null.

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DepartmentReportSelection", "Reports", new {ClientID = Model.inputParameters[0], SupplierID = Model.inputParameters[1], ReviewPeriodID = Model.inputReviewPeriodIDs, StatusCategoryID = Model.inputParameters[2]}, FormMethod.Post)) {
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CategoryTypeOptions.First().StatusCategoryID, new SelectList(Model.CategoryTypeOptions, "StatusCategoryID", "StatusCategoryDesc"), new { @class = "GRDropDown", @id = "ReportDD" })
            <input type="hidden" name="ClientID" value="@Model.ClientID" />
            if (Model.TypeOfReport == 1) {
                <input type="hidden" name="ReviewPeriodIDs" value="@Model.inputReviewPeriodIDs" />
                <input type="hidden" name="SupplierID" value="@Model.SupplierData" />
            }
            else if (Model.TypeOfReport == 2) {
                <input type="hidden" name="ReviewPeriodIDs" value="@Model.inputReviewPeriodIDs" />
            }
            else{
                <input type="hidden" name="SupplierID" value="@Model.SupplierData" />
            }

            <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default StandardButton">Filter</button>
        }
```

ActionResult:

```
 public ActionResult DepartmentReportSelection(int ClientID, string Supplier, int[] ReviewPeriodID, int? SupplierID = null, int? StatusCategoryID = null) {
            // Cut out unnecessary code 

            return View("DepartmentBreakdown", DepartmentModel);
        }
```

I'm trying to pass the in the ReviewPeriodID

Comment: In markup you have `ReviewPeriodIDs` ending with `s`, while action expects `ReviewPeriodID` without `s`. Also you might need to format it, so the value in the hidden field actually looks like `value1,value2,value3`

Comment: Hi, I dont think the markup would matter as I'm not using this to submit the value to the form. Ergo I don't think the hidden field would matter then.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DepartmentReportSelection", "Reports", new { ClientID = Model.inputParameters[0], SupplierID = Model.inputParameters[1], StatusCategoryID = Model.inputParameters[2] }, FormMethod.Post)) {
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CategoryTypeOptions.First().StatusCategoryID, new SelectList(Model.CategoryTypeOptions, "StatusCategoryID", "StatusCategoryDesc"), new { @class = "GRDropDown", @id = "ReportDD" })
            <input type="hidden" name="ClientID" value="@Model.ClientID" />
            if (Model.TypeOfReport == 1) {
                for (int i = 0; i < Model.inputReviewPeriodIDs.Length; i++) {
                    <input type="hidden" name="ReviewPeriodID" value="@Model.inputReviewPeriodIDs[i]" />
                }

                <input type="hidden" name="SupplierID" value="@Model.SupplierData" />
            }
            else if (Model.TypeOfReport == 2) {
                for (int i = 0; i < Model.inputReviewPeriodIDs.Length; i++) {
                    <input type="hidden" name="ReviewPeriodID" value="@Model.inputReviewPeriodIDs[i]" />
                }
            }
            else {
                <input type="hidden" name="SupplierID" value="@Model.SupplierData" />
            }

            <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default StandardButton">Filter</button>
        }
```

You need to create a foreach loop in the view to loop around the array and create 3 different input fields. This was I could submit it to the Action. You also cannot pass it through the route values.